# Trouble with having my password fields in phpmyadmin database to be in asterisk

Tags: javascript, php, html, c++, phpmyadmin

How do I set my password field in phpmyadmin database to be in asterisk/hash it?

I've tried MD5 & SHA1 function for the password field but it generate a new password instead of sticking with the password the employee have created. Does anyone have any idea or advice on this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve] then edit your question into a form that follows MCVE so that we can try to answer it.  If you decide this is an administration question not a programming question, visit serverfault.com

Comment: What is your goal? to avoid anyone having access to your database via phpMyAdmin to see the password in clear?

Comment: As I have a couple of users able to access the database that consists of all the employee credentials hence, I do not wish to let anyone to see the password that the employees have set for themselves.

E.g. Password field will be showing ********** instead of "password123"